# Change width for an input on Bootstrap3 horizontal forms

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-crispy-forms

Reading [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#bootstrap3-horizontal-forms) I noticed than:

> The way you do horizontal forms in Bootstrap version 3 is setting some
>   col-lg-X classes in labels and divs wrapping fields. This would mean a
>   lot of hassle updating your layout objects for settings these classes,
>   too much verbosity. Instead some FormHelper attributes have been added
>   to help you easily achieve this.

And an example is provided:

```
helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
```

My question is:

**How can I change default `label_class` or `field_class` for a form field?**

In bootstrap doc sample:

```
helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
helper.layout = Layout(
    'email',            #<--- How to set class to 'col-lg-4' only for this field?
    'password',
    'remember_me',
    StrictButton('Sign in', css_class='btn-default'),
)
```

Comment: Have you tried to wrap field into a div: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157262/django-crispy-forms-nesting-a-formset-within-a-form ?